# Links and brand name not aligned after float - Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I align the navigation links and brand name using pure CSS?
It disaligns after I include a float on the brand container and link container.
[Screenshot image here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geQXR.png)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl>
    <head>
        <title>My Portfolio</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Rocky">
        <meta name="description" content="Sample Portfolio">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Poppins">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <nav class="nav-bar">
                <section class="nav-container">
                    <section class="brand-container">
                        <h2 class="brand-name">Rocky</h2>
                    </section>

                    <ul class="link-container">
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Works</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">My Challenge</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </nav>
    </header>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header {
    height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
    background: url('../img/header_img.jpg') top center / cover fixed no-repeat;
    z-index: 1030;
}
.nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    z-index: 1031;
}
.nav-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.brand-container {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.brand-name {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    color: #444;
    background: #EEE;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.link-container {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
}
.link-container li {
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.link-container li a {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    color: #EEE;
    transition: color 150ms linear;
}
.link-container li a:hover {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

How can I fix this to align them? I tried everything like separating them and used several CSS properties to do the job it didn't worked.

Comment: The easiest way to add `margin-top:10px` in `.brand-name`.

Answer (score 0):

So floats are a pretty 'hacky' solution to setting elements to the right or left, and generally should be avoided if at all possible. Using different display settings should get the look you're going.

```
display: grid;
```

for example, will allow you to divide your nav into columns and place elements into whichever column you'd like. I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/WYPgXm) that shows what I believe is the look you're going for placement wise. If you have any questions or anything feel free to ask! I hope this helped!

Comment: Sorry I don't use CSS Grid because it has alot of issue abot compatibility.

Comment: By compatibility do you mean browser support?

Comment: CSS grid to the best of my knowledge is supported across all major browsers. Opera I think is the only one that doesn't support it. And IE and Edge just require the ms prefix.